# Fedex Integration Magento

Tags: magento, integration, fedex

I have configured FedEx to work with magento 1.7.0.2, have entered all the required parameters and have also turned on the logging. Everything seems to work fine, there are no errors anywhere and even in shipping_fedex.log file the results are successful means the quotes are returned from FedEx. But in the front end in the 'Select Shipping Method' page it's not showing up. When I choose specified countries in the configuration and put an invalid address then it shows up there with the message that it is not applicable in this situation.

Please provide me suggestion on how to solve this. Where are the FedEx code stored in magento so that i can debug them to see what the problem could be??

Comment: you can check your admin panel settings as to what rates have you allowed. most likely the response from Fedex doesn't have allowed rates.

Answer (score 1):

I came across that same situation and found out that my products were setup with weights in kilograms so some were just invalid, others would return astronomic shipping costs (like $3000 and more), when I converted the weight to pounds or fractions of pounds, it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that your shopping cart is configured correctly. Are you using the built in one page checkout module?

For general details on how to setup Magento to use FedEx webservices, please see the following URL:
   http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-setup.html